# Unlabeled break, and for statements

Tags: java, for-loop, nested, break

I don't understand the labelled `break` statement, which `for` statement. Does it stop the one just below it or the one furthest from it?

Also, I do not understand why `j` is initialized twice, why not just initialize it inside the `for` statement? Furthermore, when `j < arrayOfInts[i].length` can't `j` be an element from array `0` (that is until it increments) because `j` can be an element from an array `lower` that `arrayOfInt[i]` right?

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
            { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
        };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

    search:
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                 j++) {
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code hurts me. There's probably little reason to write like this in the first place.

Comment: j is the index of the inner array. Not en element. It can't be declared in the for loop, since it's printed after the loop. What is unclear, in the tutorial where you found this code, in "When the value is found, a labeled break terminates the outer for loop (labeled "search")". It terminates the **outer** for loop. The one which is labeled "search". But frankly, you should never use labels in the first place.

Comment: @JBNizet- Ah, I see. Thank you.